# UIWebView contents preload using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm developing an iOS app that has 2 VCs, mapVC(using google map SDK) and webVC. Selecting an annotation on mapVC, then transition to webVC with corresponding webpage openned.
But loadRequest method in viewDidLoad of webView is too slow to wait.

So I want to preload the web data when selecting a pin on mapView, and then hand over the preloaded data to webVC using loadData method.

But webVC displays only text, no images no CSS.
What should I do to preload full HTML/CSS/images? 
any advice appreciated. thanks in advance.

my current source code as follows.

```
// --- mapViewController ---
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    NSURL   *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"(target URL)"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                        timeoutInterval:60.0];
    receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection;
    urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    if (!urlConnection) {
        receivedData = nil;
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    receivedData = nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showWeb"]) {
        WebViewController   *webViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        webViewController.preloadedData = receivedData;
    }
}

// --- webViewController ---    
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.webView loadData:self.preloadedData
                  MIMEType:@"text/html"
          textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
                   baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: Are you the owner of the remote target you want to load in the webView ?

Comment: No. I want to load common web just like wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ASIWebPageRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree/master/Classes/ASIWebPageRequest). It allows the download of the entire web page, including all resources.

Comment: I checked the codes. I found it seems it downloads the page including resources in the page, into files with some file naming rules. and when uiwebview loads data, it recognises the file and loads it directly. So I guess if you want to do it by yourself, you should parse the page content first

Answer (score 1):

You have only loaded the HTML-Code but not the Content (e.g. media / images / css). You must pre parse the Response and manually pre load the rest stuff.

NSURLConnection make no look up for URL´s inside the response and no autoload

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you. So would you please tell me any other good options than NSURLConnection?

Comment: Difficult, you can use a HTML-Parser [https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser] (i found this on github, but i don´t use this...) and load the media stuff from the parsed data.

Comment: A goal is: Load the HTML-Code and load the media stuff asynchronous - it´s a little bit more comfortable für the user (he can see the text quickly...)).

Comment: Thank you for your advise. In fact, thats a good way for user to disisplay HTML in advance and later rich media asyncronously. I'll try to.